# How to make changes during boot on a read only rootfs

Tags: linux, systemd, fstab, yocto, systemd-unit

I have built a Yocto image (not based on sato) that is successfully booted, but because root is read only (in fstab), some services have failed. Mainly there is a `run-postsinsts` service that is failing with error "Read-only file system". If I change the RO part to RW in fstab, I don't get any errors (but I need RO).

I think it might be a dependency problem. The service run-postsinsts might be needed to run before fstab entries are configured (by another service).

System:

```
systemd 244 (244.5+)
Linux 5.4.193-intel-pk-standard
```

Comment: A possible solution is to use overlayfs to mount a ramfs RW directory on top of
whatever directory needs to be RW. Yocto supports overlayfs. Eg this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62171191/5008284) is to have a RW passwd file.